# The wierd behavior of localeCompare

Tags: javascript

I used this method to transform ip address to string so that I can sort my ip_array without thinking of the difference between ipv4 and ipv6.
The method is here: [inet_pton](https://github.com/kvz/locutus/blob/master/src/php/network/inet_pton.js)

Every thing was fine until I compare '0.0.0.0' to ''

You can try

`javascript
inet_pton('0.0.0.0').localeCompare('')`

It will return 0

It is really perplexing me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: But actually, inet_pton('0.0.0.0')  return a invisible string.

Comment: No, it just like '    '

but

inet_pton('0.0.0.0') === '    '   will return false

Comment: Please, can you make a try?
The code I have already written above.

Comment: `String.fromCharCode(0)` returns null character. [reference](https://www.w3schools.com/charsets/ref_html_ascii.asp). So I guess you have a string with length 4 but since its null, it might cause issue

Comment: Thank you every much!
It's really help me!